# JQuery toggle stop working after setInterval invoke

Tags: javascript, jquery

I code simple slide show using `setInterval` and also I have 2 jQuery functions for toggle div. Code seems working, but there is small issue. When I navigate to site toggle div part is working perfectly. But when first slide changes toggle functions stop working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ImageCount = 1;
    var ImageTotal = 3;

    setInterval(function SlideAuto() {
        if (ImageCount == 1) {
            ImageCount = ImageCount + 1;
        } else {
            if (ImageCount < ImageTotal) {
                ImageCount = ImageCount + 1;
            } else {
                if (ImageCount == ImageTotal) {
                    ImageCount = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        var ImageURL = 'img/SliderIMG/' + ImageCount + '.jpg';
        $("#SliderIMG").attr('src', ImageURL);
    }, 3000);

    $("#tab1").click(function () {
        $("#con1").toggle("fade");
        $("#con2").toggle("fade");
    });

    $("#tab2").click(function () {
        $("#con1").toggle("fade");
        $("#con2").toggle("fade");
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you attach example of how your HTML looks?

Comment: You can simplify your code in `setInterval` like this: `++ImageCount; if (ImageCount > ImageTotal) ImageCount = 1;`.

Comment: here I past the whole code in pastebin.

http://pastebin.com/7s0Km1mQ

Comment: Hm. Works for me: http://output.jsbin.com/wegaloteho/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: http://www.sasithmran.ga/projects/studio/test

here is a live preview. try to toggle "Contact US" after first image changed :/

Comment: Got it. It's because your `#SliderIMG` covers the text. Maybe try moving it into `background-image` and `position: absolute;`

Comment: Glad to help. :) Consider writing solution in answer to this question. It might help someone. And you'll get yourself a nice badge for this.